# Is it possible to change an asset CSS file for a webview during debugging?

Tags: android, css, debugging, webview

I have an activity which holds a webview. In the HTML code of the webview I refer to a CSS file in the "assets".

When I start debugging the app and get to the webview to see the effects of the CSS I would like to change the CSS file "on-the-fly", to see my changes after the reloading of the activity holding the webview.

Currently I changed the CSS, and then start the app, navigate to the activity with the webview and checked if it looks good. Then I go back, change the CSS and restart the app. This is very time consuming and sucks.

If changing the CSS during debugging does not work, any suggestions on how to achieve quick CSS editing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cant modify the asset folder**. You can copy the file from asset folder to sd card from following code:

```
private void CopyAssetsbrochure() {

        File direct = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "songs");

        direct.mkdirs();

        AssetManager assetManager = this._context.getResources().getAssets();

        String[] files = null;

        try {
            files = assetManager.list("songs"); // songs is folder
                                                        // name
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open("songs" + File.separator
                        + files[i]);
                out = new FileOutputStream(
                        android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "songs"
                                + File.separator + files[i]);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[65536 * 2];
                int read;
                while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
                Log.d("copy", "Ringtone File Copied in SD Card");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", "ERROR: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

And dont forget to give permission to manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edited**:

> Currently I changed the CSS, and then start the app, navigate to the
>   activity with the webview and checked if it looks good. Then I go
>   back, change the CSS and restart the app. This is very time consuming
>   and sucks.

As css is used for webview and webview is loading under the activity there is no way without restarting the app. Because **there is no refresh(F5) method like browser** to make your page refresh to load all the changes you have done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
Ok. I understand. I dont want to put the css file into the external storage, or add a addtional permission, because my issue changing the css is just for development. When the application is deployed, the css is not to be changed.

Comment: Are you changing the css stuff dynamically? @Klaus

Comment: I would like to change the css during debugging of the app dynamically to see the changes right away without restarting the debugging process. When I think the CSS is finished, there is no need for the app to change the css dynamically anymore. Just for development purposes. @Andru

Comment: And I don't know who downvote it but still I think it was the expected answer as user wanted to modify the asset folder. right @osayilgan

Comment: You can use a button to refresh the css. Simply, when you need to change something in css file, go to device's sd card, find your css, make changes and over write your css file there in the sd card. then make a click listener for that button and in onClick, read the css file again from sd card, and load it again to your web view.

Comment: @osayilgan is there any reason behind the downvote in my answer?.

Comment: @Andru there is a way to do it. You can re-read the file in your sd card whenever you make changes into css file. You Don't need to restart the app !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42573/discussion-between-andru-and-osayilgan)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the file in "assets" folder, it's compiled with your application. What you can do is, copy the css file to your sd card to a certain path then use it from there.

P.S : Don't forget to give read & write permissions.